# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function getPaths(pathIds, subCategory, callback){
    var currentCategory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subCategory));
    console.log(currentCategory);
    console.log(currentCategory.name);
    var paths = [];
    var pathDirs = "";
    for (i=0; i<pathIds.length; i++) {
        pathDirs += pathIds[i];
        paths[i] = {dir : pathDirs, name : currentCategory.name};
        currentCategory = currentCategory.categories.find(function(category){
            return category.id = pathIds[i];
        });
    }
    callback(paths);
}
```

I am new to js and node.js. I receive the above error and I consider it refers to the currentCategory.name property. When I type console.log (currentCategory), I have the entire object printed including the name property. 
What could have I done wrong?

Here is the stack trace I got for further info:

```
D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at getPaths (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\routes.js:124:54)
at D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\routes.js:24:4
at D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\routes.js:112:3
at result (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
at executeCallback (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:406:9)
at handleCallback (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
at cursor.close (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\cursor_ops.js:218:62)
at handleCallback (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
at completeClose (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:887:14)
at _endSession (D:\repos\onlineStore\borrislava-onlinestore\Backup\Work\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:898:37)
```

Comment: You have a loop and you only print the first value of `currentCategory`. It is modified inside the loop so move your console.log there to see better

Comment: I see now - first loop is ok, but after that code execution gets asynchronious. Is there a way I can reuse currentCategory object in the next loops?

Comment: Can you provide more code? Like the getPaths function invokation with both the pathIds array and the subCategory object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues in your loop :

```
for (i=0; i<pathIds.length; i++) {
    pathDirs += pathIds[i];
    paths[i] = {dir : pathDirs, name : currentCategory.name};
    currentCategory = currentCategory.categories.find(function(category){
        return category.id = pathIds[i];
    });
}
```

1 - [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find) will return the first element matching the condition in the return clause of the provided function.

If none element matches the condition, `undefined` is affected to the `currentCategory` variable. Then, when looping again, `currentCategory` is undefined and you get :

> TypeError : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

2 - There's also a typo in your return clause. You're setting `category.id` instead of comparing it to `pathIds[i]` :

```
return category.id = pathIds[i]
```

Are you sure you don't want to compare them instead? Because right now, you're setting category.id and returning it in your function. So, the function you provided to your `find` will return false if `pathIds[i]` is equal to 0, and true otherwise. Is that really what you want?

Comment: There is always an element matching the condition. This should not be a problem.

Comment: What if a category doesn't have any subCategories? In this case, find will return undefined and you'll get your error on the next loop iteration.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you!! :) There was a problem with loops which resulted in the undefined value.